# Naturally aligned memory address

Tags: c, memory, binary, bit-shift

I need to extract a memory address from within an existing 64-bit value, and this address points to a 4K array, the starting value is:

```
0x000000030c486000
```

The address I need is stored within bits 51:12, so I extract those bits using:

```
address = start >> 12 & 0x0000007FFFFFFFFF
```

This leaves me with the address of:

```
0x000000000030c486
```

However, the documentation I'm reading states that the array stored at the address is 4KB in size, and naturally aligned.

I'm a little bit confused over what naturally aligned actually means.  I know with page aligned stuff the address normally ends with '000' (although I could be wrong on that).

I'm assuming that as the address taken from the starting value is only 40 bits long, I need to perform an additional bitshifting operation to arrange the bits so that they can be correctly interpreted any further.

If anyone could offer some advice on doing this, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Note that if the limits are inclusive, there are 40 bits from bit No. 12 to bit No. 51. You probably need to shift the mask instead of the address, `address = start & (0x000000FFFFFFFFFF << 12);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, "naturally aligned" means that any item is aligned to at least a multiple of its own size. For example, a 4-byte object is aligned to an address that's a multiple of 4, an 8-byte object is aligned to an address that's a multiple of 8, etc.

For an array, you don't normally look at the size of the whole array, but at the size of an element of the array.

Likewise, for a `struct` or `union`, you normally look at the size of the largest element.

Comment: Well in this case, the array is 512 64-bit longs, so in theory then, the address I'm getting from bits 51:12 should point to first element in that array?

Answer (score 2):

A “naturally aligned” address is one that is a multiple of some value that is preferred for the data type on the processor. For most elementary data types on most common processors, the preferred alignment is the same as the size of the data: Four-byte integers should be aligned on multiples of four bytes, eight-byte floating-point should be aligned on multiples of eight bytes, and so on. Some platforms require alignment, some merely prefer it. Some types have alignment requirements different from their sizes. For example, a 12-byte `long float` may require four-byte alignment. Specific values depend in your target platform. “Naturally aligned” is not a formal term, so some people might define it only as preferred alignment that is a multiple of the data size, while others might allow it to be used for other alignments that are preferred on the processor.

Taking bits out of a 64-bit value suggests the address has been transformed in some way. For example, key bits from the address have been stored in a page table entry. Reconstructing the original address might or might not be as simple as extracting the bits and shifting them all the way to the “right” (low end). However, it is also common for bits such as this to be shifted to a different position (with zeroes left in the low bits). You should check the documentation carefully.

Note that a 4 KiB array, 4096 bytes, corresponds to 2<sup>12</sup> bytes. The coincidence of 12 with the 51:12 field in the 64-bit value suggests that the address might be obtained simply by extracting those 40 bits without shifting them at all.

Answer (score 2):

Natural alignment requires that every N byte access must be aligned on a memory address boundary of N. We can express this in terms of the modulus operator: addr % N must be zero. for examples:

Accessing 4 bytes of memory from address 0x10004 is aligned (0x10004 % 4 = 0).

Accessing 4 bytes of memory from address 0x10005 is unaligned (0x10005 % 4 = 1).

Answer (score 2):

From a hardware perspective, memory is typically divided into chunks of some size, such that any or all of the data within a chunk can be read or written in a single operation, but any single operation can only affect data within a single chunk.

A typical 80386-era system would have memory grouped into four-byte chunks.  Accessing a two-byte or four-byte value which fit entirely within a single chunk would require one operation.  If the value was stored partially in one chunk and partially in another, two operations would be required.

Over the years, chunk sizes have gotten larger than data sizes, to the point that most randomly-placed 32-bit values would fit entirely within a chunk, but a second issue may arise with some processors: if a chunk is e.g. 512 bits (64 bytes) and a 32-bit word is known to be aligned at a multiple of four bytes (32 bits), fetching each bit of the word can come from any of 16 places.  If the word weren't known to be aligned, each bit could come from any of 61 places for the cases where the word fits entirely within the chunk.  The circuitry to quickly select from among 61 choices is more complex than circuitry to select among 16, and most code will use aligned data, so even in cases where an unaligned word would fit within a single accessible chunk, hardware might still need a little extra time to extract it.

Comment: Fantastic explanation. Thank you.